# Python JSON formatting question for class project

Tags: python, json, format

I'm working on a project for a Intro to programming logic class for school where we are reading in information from a .txt file, reformatitng it to JSON format and then writing that JSON format to a new .txt file while also printing the JSON formatted data to the screen.

I'm having an issue where my JSON key value pairs are putting quotes on data types that do not need quotes, such as integers and booleans.

```py
def main():
    runtimeManager = RuntimeManager()
    jsonResult = runtimeManager.run()
    outputFileName=runtimeManager.outputFilename
    print(jsonResult)
    print("\nOutput written to " +outputFileName+ ".")

class RuntimeManager:

    def run(self):
        ## Gather required member variables
        self.getUserInputFileName()
        self.getUserOutputFileName()

        ##Grabbing user file and extracting the CSV
        with open(self.inputFilename) as inputFile:
            jsonResult = CsvToJson(inputFile.readlines()).transformCsvToJson()
            with open(self.outputFilename, "w") as outputFile:
                outputFile.write(jsonResult)
            return jsonResult


    def getUserInputFileName(self):
        ## Prompt User for 
        self.inputFilename = input("Enter the filename:  ").strip()

    def getUserOutputFileName(self):
        self.outputFilename = input("Enter the OUTPUT filename:  ").strip()



class CsvToJson():

    def __init__(self, csv):
        self.csv = csv
        self.headers = csv[0].strip()
        self.data = csv[1:]

    def transformCsvToJson(self):
        jsonResult = "{"
        for i in range(0, len(self.data)):
            if (i != 0):
                jsonResult = jsonResult + "\n,"
            jsonResult = jsonResult + "\"" + str(i+1) + "\":" + self.createJsonObject(self.headers, self.data[i])
        return jsonResult + "\n}"

    def createJsonObject(self, headers, csvRow):
        csvKeyArray = headers.split(",")
        csvValueArray = csvRow.strip().split(",")
        jsonObject = "{"
        for i in range(0, len(csvKeyArray)):
            jsonField = ""
            if (i != 0):
                jsonField = ","
            jsonField = jsonField + "\"" + str(csvKeyArray[i]) + "\":" + self.getValueDataType(csvValueArray[i])
            jsonObject = jsonObject + jsonField
        return jsonObject + "}"

    def getValueDataType(self, value):
        if (type(value) == int):
            value = str(value)
        elif (type(value) == str):
            value = "\"" + value + "\""
        elif (type(value) == bool):
            if (value):
                value = "true"
            else:
                value = "false"
        elif (type(value) == null):
            value = "null"
        else:
            value = "ERROR"

        return value


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

I've put my program in here with line numbers. The stipulations of my assignment dictate that we are not permitted to use the JSON module built into python.

the issue I'm having is my JSON formatting looks like this:

```json
{"1":{"Last Name":"Minion","First Name":"Bob","Preferred Name":"Bob","Preferred Pronoun":"he/him","SF ID #":"2211-4456","Program Code":"3504","Phone":"910-432-8765","Email":"bob.minion@go.sfcollege.edu"}
```

and it should look like this:

```json
{"1":{"Last Name":"Minion","First Name":"Bob","Preferred Name":"Bob","Preferred Pronoun":"he/him","SF ID #":"2211-4456","Program Code":3504,"Phone":"910-432-8765","Email":"bob.minion@go.sfcollege.edu"}
```

with the quotes not being on the code in the Program Code:3504 key value pair, and I can't figure out why the quotes are being placed on it.

example input file content looks like this:

```
Last Name,First Name,Preferred Name,Preferred Pronoun,SF ID #,Program Code,Phone,Email
Minion,Bob,Bob,he/him,2211-4456,3504,910-432-8765,bob.minion@go.sfcollege.edu
Nichols,James,James,,1234-5678,3651,352-395-5220,james.nichols@sfcollege.edu
Person,Punny,,,9999-1111,3840,352-123-4567,punny.person@go.sfcollege.edu
Person,Punny2,,,9999-1112,3841,352-123-6792,punny2.person@go.sfcollege.edu
Person,Punny3,,,9999-1113,3842,352-123-3420,punny3.person@go.sfcollege.edu
Smart,Maxwell,Max,,9922-4029,3650,310-2910,agent.smart@go.sfcollege.edu
Tree,Groot,Groot,,1122-3344,3624,361-1234-5678,groot.tree@go.sfcollege.edu
```

Comment: Please remove the line numbers and just give us the program itself.

Comment: And to answer your question, you are assuming the data you read are integers, but they're not. When you split a string it returns a list of strings. That's what your `csvValueArray` is. You have to write your own logic to convert certain strings in that list to integers or other types.

Comment: Line Numbers Removed

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample content of the input file?

Comment: example input file added

Comment: Something can be said about the input data for sure? For example, can we say that only integers, floating-point numbers, strings and empty values can occur in the input data? Or maybe we can say that the set of columns is fixed, they are always named exactly as shown in the example and always contain only data of a specific type?

Answer (score 0):

All values from a split CSV line are type `str` which is why you get quotes around everything.  You could write a `coerce` function that tests if the string can be converted to `int`:

```
    def coerce(value):
        try:
            return int(value)
        except ValueError:
            return value
            
    def getValueDataType(self, value):
        value = self.coerce(value)
        if (type(value) == int):
            value = str(value)
        ...
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to coerce `bool` and `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, where *s* is the *JSON string*.

There is no character escaping, in this one.

```py
j = ''
h = next(it := iter(s.splitlines())).split(',')
for r in it:
    a = ''
    for k, v in zip(h, (c := r.split(','))):
        if not v: v = 'null'
        elif not (v in ['true', 'false', 'null'] or v.isnumeric()):
            v = f'"{v}"'
        if a: a += ','
        a += f'"{k}": {v}'
    if j: j += ',\n'
    j += '{' + a + '}'
j = f'[{j}]'
```

Output

```json
[{"Last Name": "Minion","First Name": "Bob","Preferred Name": "Bob","Preferred Pronoun": "he/him","SF ID #": "2211-4456","Program Code": 3504,"Phone": "910-432-8765","Email": "bob.minion@go.sfcollege.edu"},
{"Last Name": "Nichols","First Name": "James","Preferred Name": "James","Preferred Pronoun": null,"SF ID #": "1234-5678","Program Code": 3651,"Phone": "352-395-5220","Email": "james.nichols@sfcollege.edu"},
{"Last Name": "Person","First Name": "Punny","Preferred Name": null,"Preferred Pronoun": null,"SF ID #": "9999-1111","Program Code": 3840,"Phone": "352-123-4567","Email": "punny.person@go.sfcollege.edu"},
{"Last Name": "Person","First Name": "Punny2","Preferred Name": null,"Preferred Pronoun": null,"SF ID #": "9999-1112","Program Code": 3841,"Phone": "352-123-6792","Email": "punny2.person@go.sfcollege.edu"},
{"Last Name": "Person","First Name": "Punny3","Preferred Name": null,"Preferred Pronoun": null,"SF ID #": "9999-1113","Program Code": 3842,"Phone": "352-123-3420","Email": "punny3.person@go.sfcollege.edu"},
{"Last Name": "Smart","First Name": "Maxwell","Preferred Name": "Max","Preferred Pronoun": null,"SF ID #": "9922-4029","Program Code": 3650,"Phone": "310-2910","Email": "agent.smart@go.sfcollege.edu"},
{"Last Name": "Tree","First Name": "Groot","Preferred Name": "Groot","Preferred Pronoun": null,"SF ID #": "1122-3344","Program Code": 3624,"Phone": "361-1234-5678","Email": "groot.tree@go.sfcollege.edu"}]
```

If you wanted to include character escaping, here is a re-factor.
There is an *[RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)* which defines the values.
*[RFC 8259 – The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format – Section 7. Strings](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#autoid-10)*.

```py
import unicodedata
j = ''
h = next(it := iter(s.splitlines())).split(',')
for r in it:
    a = ''
    for k, v in zip(h, (c := r.split(','))):
        if not v: v = 'null'
        elif not (v in ['true', 'false', 'null'] or v.isnumeric()):
            v = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', v)
            v = str(v.encode('unicode_escape'), 'utf-8')
            if '"' in v: v = v.replace('"', r'\"')
            v = f'"{v}"'
        if a: a += ','
        a += f'"{k}": {v}'
    if j: j += ',\n'
    j += '{' + a + '}'
j = f'[{j}]'
```

And, if you want to indent the lines, here is another re-factor.

```py
import unicodedata
j = ''
h = next(it := iter(s.splitlines())).split(',')
for r in it:
    a = ''
    for k, v in zip(h, (c := r.split(','))):
        if not v: v = 'null'
        elif not (v in ['true', 'false', 'null'] or v.isnumeric()):
            v = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', v)
            v = str(v.encode('unicode_escape'), 'utf-8')
            if '"' in v: v = v.replace('"', r'\"')
            v = f'"{v}"'
        if a: a += f',\n{(" " * 8)}'
        a += f'"{k}": {v}'
    if j: j += ',\n'
    j += (' ' * 4) + '{\n' + f'{(" " * 8)}{a}\n{(" " * 4)}' + '}'
j = f'[\n{j}\n]'
```

Output

```json
[
    {
        "Last Name": "Minion",
        "First Name": "Bob",
        "Preferred Name": "Bob",
        "Preferred Pronoun": "he/him",
        "SF ID #": "2211-4456",
        "Program Code": 3504,
        "Phone": "910-432-8765",
        "Email": "bob.minion@go.sfcollege.edu"
    },
    {
        "Last Name": "Nichols",
        "First Name": "James",
        "Preferred Name": "James",
        "Preferred Pronoun": null,
        "SF ID #": "1234-5678",
        "Program Code": 3651,
        "Phone": "352-395-5220",
        "Email": "james.nichols@sfcollege.edu"
    },
    {
        "Last Name": "Person",
        "First Name": "Punny",
        "Preferred Name": null,
        "Preferred Pronoun": null,
        "SF ID #": "9999-1111",
        "Program Code": 3840,
        "Phone": "352-123-4567",
        "Email": "punny.person@go.sfcollege.edu"
    },
    {
        "Last Name": "Person",
        "First Name": "Punny2",
        "Preferred Name": null,
        "Preferred Pronoun": null,
        "SF ID #": "9999-1112",
        "Program Code": 3841,
        "Phone": "352-123-6792",
        "Email": "punny2.person@go.sfcollege.edu"
    },
    {
        "Last Name": "Person",
        "First Name": "Punny3",
        "Preferred Name": null,
        "Preferred Pronoun": null,
        "SF ID #": "9999-1113",
        "Program Code": 3842,
        "Phone": "352-123-3420",
        "Email": "punny3.person@go.sfcollege.edu"
    },
    {
        "Last Name": "Smart",
        "First Name": "Maxwell",
        "Preferred Name": "Max",
        "Preferred Pronoun": null,
        "SF ID #": "9922-4029",
        "Program Code": 3650,
        "Phone": "310-2910",
        "Email": "agent.smart@go.sfcollege.edu"
    },
    {
        "Last Name": "Tree",
        "First Name": "Groot",
        "Preferred Name": "Groot",
        "Preferred Pronoun": null,
        "SF ID #": "1122-3344",
        "Program Code": 3624,
        "Phone": "361-1234-5678",
        "Email": "groot.tree@go.sfcollege.edu"
    }
]
```